# Put clickable Icon next to bootstrap navbar toggle

Tags: css, class, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive

I would like to put a clickable icon next to the navbar toggle on a website using bootstrap.

I've tried playing with pull and align classes, but with no luck.

Regards

Comment: Show the code what you tried, otherwise people will downvote you. You could even create a fiddle, so we can help better.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you want somethig like a button right next to the toggle button when the navbar collapses.

One way to do it, is to create an `<a>` right in the `.navbar-brand` and to pull it right with `.pull-right`. For styling you can use a `.btn` (or you can choose what ever you want).

Important here is to hide this clickable icon on the screenviews where you have no toggle button, for this you can use the `.hidden-md` and `.hidden-lg` classes

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/18727/)

Hope this helps you.

P.S.: Of course the `<a>` in the `.navbar-brand` also should use `.navbar-brand` to be well aligned.